# .NET WebSockets and TCP_NODELAY

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, nagle

Is it possible to build a WebSocket Client in C#.NET that allows me to set the TCP_NODELAY property to True on the socket (i.e. disable Nagle)? I have tried a bunch of WebSocket libraries that don't appear to have this option.
Thanks

Comment: See codeproject : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server

Comment: Thanks, but this is a server implementation, I'm looking for a client

Comment: _"set the TCP_NODELAY property to False on the socket (i.e. disable Nagle)"_ -- first, you need to figure out what it is you're actually trying to do. The default value for `TCP_NODELAY` is false, so you don't need to set it to false. The false state corresponds to Nagle's algorithm being _enabled_, not disabled. Beyond that, your question is way too broad... _"is it possible?"_ Sure, it's always possible. The only question is how much work you want to put into it. How much work have _you_ put into this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say True not False. I'm sending data that needs to stream with no pauses. Was wondering if this was possible to do with Microsoft's WebSockets. I found how to do it on the Server end.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding an open sourced WebSocket library that I was able to add NoDelay support to.

Comment: Please share the library name